# Is it possible to write a text onto multiple textboxes at once in C# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Is it possible to write a text onto multiple textboxes at once (see code)? Instead of writing the text into the textboxes one at a time is there any simpler syntax to do this?

I know I can use a for loop for this, but is there any other way instead of using loops?

Thank you!

Example code:

```
DateTime tpi1 = DateTime.Now;

tb05.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb05.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
tb15.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb15.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
tb25.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb25.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
tb35.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb35.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
tb45.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb45.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
tb55.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => tb55.Text = tpi1.ToString()));
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can for example create a collection of textbox and foreach on it to change Text, or use `Controls.TypeOf<TextBox>` and `Where` using some serach pattern like `"tbXX"`. What does fit?

Comment: When I use a loop, it causes a little delay which should be avoided for the other part of my code to work. But I will look into Control.TypeOf as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure you need `Invoke` in the first place? If you do, make a single `Invoke` and loop inside its lambda.

Comment: You can also add one event handler on each text box, thus when you change one, all the others will be changed. I would prefer this option, in theory, without considering other things and only the provided code. Why Invoke? Is this code in a separated thread?

Comment: I'm a beginner in c# programming. I just wanted to avoid cross-thread operation error that's why I used it.

Comment: Do a single invoke. And perhaps `tb1.Text = tb2.Text = ... = tpi1.ToString()` is good enough.

Answer (score -3):

i wouldn't do that but technically you could do it with an MVVM approach over WinForm